# Is the Windows service "Session Detection" (SessionService.exe) safe?

Tags: windows

I was restarting a service and happened to notice that I had one service running that had no description. This struck me as curious. It's called "Session Detection" and is located at `c:\windows\system32\drivers\SessionService.exe`.  I checked the file properties and it has no details; no publisher, no product name, etc.  I did some googling and didn't find anything negative, but I also didn't find anything reassuring (like I would expect for a typical Windows service).  This, coupled with no description, had me a bit concerned. I uploaded the file to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/39a6192be5b730c2668a189d0ee08fec20eb94d97572f75b247f6fba6fcc5779) and it shows it's clean and distributed by MS. I also installed and ran Malwarebytes. Clean.

So I guess my real question is what does this service do? Why doesn't it have a description like *every other* Windows service?

Answer (score 3):

### Safe? Yes, if you have a Dell laptop and/or fingerprint reader

**Evidence 1:** I saw the same service running on my machine, and as I did a clean install of Windows just 2 weeks ago there is a reduced chance of this being Malware due to limited amount of time it has been in use and the nature of it being up-to-date from the moment O/S was installed.

**Evidence 2:** Multiple sources ([freefixer.com](https://www.freefixer.com/library/file/SessionService.exe-310851/), [pconlife.com](https://www.pconlife.com/viewfileinfo/sessionservice-exe)) report this file as from **Goodix**, I have a Dell G3 laptop and know that it has a Goodix fingerprint reader.

**Evidence 3:** As further cross-checking with the above, I re-downloaded the Goodix Fingerprint driver from [Dell.com](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-uk/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=7nnnp&oscode=w2021) and can confirm that the driver installer contains `SessionService.exe`

[image]

As with anything with regard to security online, its good to be vigilant and check everything that looks suspicious however in this case (and again, especially if you have a Dell laptop or other device that has a Goodix fingerpint reader) I think this file should be pretty safe.